# Android: Type without superclass: module-info

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, build.gradle

With literally nothing changed since 2 days ago my app isn't building at all. `transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug` is failing on every single branch in the whole project. I'm suspecting some issue with Firebase or GCM but I haven't changed their versions. I'm using Android Studio 3.2 and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0`.

Here is the log of the crash. Invalidating cache, clean build or similar solutions aren't working. It is even reproducible on different computers running different versions of Android Studio and Mac OS.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type without superclass: module-info
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:191)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:80)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(ClassVisitor.java:113)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visit(InterfaceDesugaring.java:97)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:621)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
```

Comment: Also removing FirebasePerformancePlugin did not solve anything so far

Comment: Did it work for anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurred because of different versions of an indirect dependency which was incompatible with its previous version. Some libraries we were using already updated to a newer version of this specific dependency, while others did not. Having them both was causing the crash.

Solution was running `androidDependencies`, checking where the inconsistencies occur and then forcing android to use a single version of the specific library by including it in your own dependencies.

Comment: What kind of inconsistencies am I looking for when I run that task?

Comment: @FutureShocked For us it was different versions of Byte Buddy.

Comment: But how did you actually determine those inconsistencies? Just manually checking versions of each dependency?

Comment: Sadly yes. You can try and find when the builds started crashing and see if any library got updated around this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has the same issue from github -> [Using latest version with Android, results in broken build](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-convert/issues/24)

> For documentation, only way to include ***"classifier"*** in Gradle build
>   dependencies specification is this
>
> ```
>  dependencies {
>      implementation group: 'org.joda', name: 'joda-convert', version: '2.0.1', classifier: 'classic' }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved when I upgraded Android Studio to v3.3, and gradle to the latest (5.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

maybe cause: Add module-info for standard library artifacts from kotlin 1.4.
see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21266

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in `app/Build.gradle`:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Me too, I am using Android Studio 3.2 with Gradle 3.2.0 and GradleWrapper 4.10.2